# httpclient.Execute very slow on Android

Tags: android

I am using httpclient.execute(httppost) and its taking about 10 seconds to send a tiny file to my webserver. When I upload the same file using the web browser on the phone it takes less than 1 second. Here is my code

```
   String urlString = "http://xxxxx/upload.php";

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);

        File file = new File(pic);

        Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: setting up multipart entity");

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: file length = " + file.length());
        Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: file exist = " + file.exists());

        mpEntity.addPart("uploadedfile", new FileBody(file, "application/octet"));
     // mpEntity.addPart("id", new StringBody("1"));

        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: executing request: " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: request: " + httppost.getEntity().getContentType().toString());


        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: about to execute");
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: executed");
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: respose code: " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
            if (resEntity != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "UPLOAD: " + EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
            if (resEntity != null) {
                resEntity.consumeContent();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is there a bug on Android preventing the uploading of files quickly from within an App?

Answer (score 3):

Android Team recommends using `HttpUrlConnection` instead of `HttpClient` http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: Thanks for this, I tired HttpUrlConnection also and its very slow. I asked a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581289/opening-datainputstream-running-very-slow . I decided to try and use another method as there does not seem to be a solution?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920623/sometimes-httpurlconnection-getinputstream-executes-too-slowly

Comment: Thanks, its still the same. The upload appears to happen quickly, but the reading the response takes forever.

Comment: Do you need the text of response? Maybe just check the [`HttpUrlConnections.getResponseCode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode()) will do the work without opening input stream?

Comment: I need to get the html reply from the server. Its very strange, the file does not copy to the server when I call the inStream = new DataInputStream( connection.getInputStream() ); command. Surely the file should be copied before this is called?